# What index should be created for low cardinality high updating columns in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, database-administration, database-indexes

In Oracle 11g, say, I have a table `Task` which has a column `ProcessState`. The values of this column can be `Queued`, `Running` and `Complete` (can have couple more states in future). The table will have 50M+ data with 99.9% of rows having `Complete` as that column value. Only a few thousand rows will have value `Queued`/`Running`.

I read that although `bitmap` index is good for low cardinality column, but that is used largely for static tables.

So, what index can improve the query for `Queued`/`Running` tasks? `bitmap` or normal non-unique `b-tree` index?

Also, what index can improve the query for a binary column (`NUMBER(1,0)` with just `yes`/`no` values) ?

Disclaimer: I am an accidental dba.

Comment: In your case the  "bitmap index" is more preferable. You said "...99.9% of rows having Complete..." in case you UPDATE the Task.ProcessState from only one session you will have no performance impact otherwise sessions will have to serialize it's access to index.

Comment: What is the query you are trying to improve?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Like this: `select task_id from task where processstate=0` (expecting only < 500 rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular (b*tree) index is fine.  Just make sure there is a histogram on the column.  (See `METHOD_OPT` parameter in `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS`).

With a histogram on that column, Oracle will have the data it needs to make sure it uses the index when looking for queued/running jobs but use a full table scan when looking for completed job.

Do *NOT* use a bitmap index, as suggested in the comments.  With lots of updates, you'll have concurrency and, worse, deadlocking issues.

> Also, what index can improve the query for a binary column (NUMBER(1,0) with just yes/no values)

Sorry -- I missed this part of your question.  If the data in the column is skewed (i.e., almost all 1 or almost all 0), then a regular (b*tree) index as above.  If the data is evenly distributed, then no index will help.  Reading 50% of your table's rows via an index will be slower than a full table scan.

Comment: *A regular (b-tree) index is fine* — it is but it's inefficient to include growing complete-state rows set into the index. The only appropriate method for growing complete state records set in *general case* is FTS. So we get overhead in index maintenance with no gain of it. So IMHO it is nice to index non-Complete state rows only.

Comment: I tried to keep my answer simple; using the information given.  It sounds to me like the OP was thrust into a DBA role and is trying to improve the performance of an existing application.  Function based indexes can be used to omit "completed" records, but then you have to change the application queries to use the same function or else you get no benefit.  I didn't assume that he has the time, authority, etc to make such changes.  With the table he's described and the query goals he's given, a b*tree index on ProcessState will be a quick and effective solution, even if it does waste some space

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you are interested in selecting rows with (Queued/Running) states for updating them. So it would be nice **to separate** the completed rows from the others because there is no much sence in indexing completed rows. You can use *paritioning* here or *function-based index* with function returning `NULL` for completed rows and actual values for the others, in this case only uncompleted rows appears in an index tree.